# Additive Approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation

Background

We are all very familiar with the concept of a linear approximation. For a 2D smooth real-valued function $f$, the first-order Taylor expansion is $f(x,y)\approx f(x_{0},y_{0})+(x-x_{0})f_{x}(x_{0},y_{0})+(y-y_{0})f_{y}(x_{0},y_{0})$. Loosely speaking, this formula solves the problem of getting a "locally optimal" linear approximation

$L(x,y) = A\langle x-x_{0}, y-y_{0}\rangle ^{T}$, where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. Within the broader topic of "generalized linear models" there is a notion of an "additive linear model." In this case, we are looking for an approximation of the form $A(x,y) = g(x)+h(y)$ for smooth 1D functions $g$ and $h$.

Smoothness is not necessarily required for additive approximations in general, but it is a natural condition to add in this question. Obviously this is a much larger set of functions, but it preserves some useful properties of linearity.

Question

I think the most obvious method for generating $g$ and $h$ would be to approximate them using 1D Taylor approximations. Then, the whole additive approximation would be a potentially high-order Taylor approximation minus the cross terms. In some cases this would perform very well, but we could only guarantee $O(xy)$ convergence. Can this be improved upon?

Context:
I have worked on some "engineering math" problems where the coefficients in a linear approximation are treated as proxies for "how much impact" each variable in a system is having on some objective function of interest (see: [sensitivity coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) and especially "Derivative-based local methods"). In some cases, it seems like [additive models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_model) (already used in some data science applications due to their explainability) could potentially do this with higher-accuracy. There's probably some issue with doing things this way or I would have heard about it already but who knows. Maybe there's a non-trivial application here.

Comment: "What is the best way  to produce a locally-accurate additive approximation?"  That requires opinions of users, meaning we consider such questions "opinion-based".  Buried in your collage of words posted her,is that sole question, unfortunately opinion-based.  Please refrain from excessive use of *********

Comment: @amWhy I can edit to add a definition of "optimal" if you wish, though I thought this fairly obvious from context. Is the term "collage of words" supposed to mean that I should have written less? What context would you cut?

Comment: It would help a lot to add a criteria that you clearly operationalize: if "Optimal", define what qualifies as optimal.  Your post is fine; before my edit it appeared more wordy.  To Boldface titles of sections, stick to ** on each side of the title. This post is definitely worth the edit.

Comment: @amWhy I made the question more specific and removed the word "optimal" (from the question not the post) entirely.

Comment: I appreciate it!  Thanks.